# How can I access a particular ad copy by AdID for a single (my own) Google Ads account?

Tags: google-ads, api, google-api

We are getting AdID from the incoming clicks using ValueTrack.

Now, we're trying to get the COPY of the ad using this AdID.

Do I need a full-blown Google Ads Manager Account and API to access a particular ad by AdID for a single GoogleAds account or is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: PS. I figured out a way to create a report that would export all the needed data as an XML file. We can process the file to get everything we need.

Question: I don't want to manually export it every time we make a change in our campaign. I see there is a way to send it daily by email, but the question is, how do we get that email attachment to be processed by our server software?